# Azure sql database export to storage blob failed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I tried to export Sql Database in azure to storage blob but the operation failed. I do this task daily last month and this issue is new. It shows as follows :

Error encountered during the service operation.Blob https://blob link/dbname-2019-1-16-14-24.bacpac is not writeable. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: Do you check your **SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE**? if it's expired, then will deny the access.

Comment: This is happening with our sub too. Looks like an Azure internal error.

Comment: @ZairHenrique Same thing here. Can't export a db since yesterday... will try again tomorrow.

Comment: Fyi, pinged Azure support about this, they are investigating. https://twitter.com/AzureSupport/status/1085920629604474881

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I have contacted Azure support and this is their response.

> We recently identified a regression in the import/export service that is generating incorrect SAS tokens to the storage accounts.
>
> The engineering team has rolled out the fix, but it might take some time for the fix to get applied worldwide.
>
> Please try the following link to access Azure portal and then perform the export operations:
>
> https://portal.azure.com/?feature.canmodifystamps=true&microsoft_azure_storage=stage1
>
> The portal shows an orange title bar if you open it via the above link, this is expected.

So, it should be already fixed by now.

Comment: It seems to be working fine again today. likely an azure internal issue

Comment: The bug is not fix! I can backup the db only through your link!

Comment: @Evilripper the bugfix is probably still rolling out. I am happy that the link worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sql scripts for back up following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-2017#credential), then I suspect that the expired date of **SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE** is reached.

Please re-generate **SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE**, and then use the new key for backup.

Please let me know if any more issues.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I am not using sql scripts. I only use azure portal export option

Comment: I also uses the same blob account to upload files from application and it's working fine. Only issue is when exporting db from azure portal

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a firewall rule does not exist. Please go to the Azure portal "Storage Accounts → "YourStorageAccountName" → Firewalls and Virtual Networks (left vertical panel). Put it to "Allow access" from "All networks". You can also configure the storage account with exceptions for trusted Microsoft services as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#exceptions).

Comment: It's already set to Allow access from all networks but not working